# Access container started at Docker Compose step from Hosted Linux Agent on Azure VSTS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using VSTS build step Docker Compose v 0.* on Hosted Linux Agent.
Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  storage:
    image: blobstorageemulator:1.1
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
  server:
    build: .
    environment:
      - ENV=--tests
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - storage
```

I use run services command.
So basically I am running 2 Linux containers inside another Linux container (Build Agent).
I was able to connect these containers to each other (server uses storage through connection string, which contains `storage` as a host - `http://storage:10000/devstoreaccount1`).
Question: how to get access to the `server` from the build agent container? When I do `curl http://localhost:8080` on the next step it returns `Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused.`
PS
Locally I run docker compose and can easily access my exposed port from host OS (I have VirtualBox with Ubuntu 17.10)

UPDATE:
I tried using `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' server-container-name` to get the IP address of the container running my server app and curl this IP, but I am getting connection timed out now.

Comment: Try to access it through actual IP (not localhost or 127.0.0.1) https://mderriey.com/2017/03/06/playing-with-vsts-linux-agent-and-docker/

Comment: What's the result if you try it with private agent?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT same, can't discover this endpoint.

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log)

Comment: @AT running on private agent means you have tried with the agent running inside container right?

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to access it from the host container, you have to perform exec command.

```
docker-compose -p container_name exec name_from_compose http://localhost:8080
```